# How to use a production WSGI server for Firebase Cloud Functions in Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions, wsgi

I implemented production ready functions in python that I want to deploy on Cloud Functions. When I do so using the following command :

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I get the following Warning message.

```
...
* Serving Flask app 'serving'
* Debug mode: off

WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:8081
...
```

Do I need to act on it? Is there a way to use a production WSGI server? Why isn't it setup by default?